# Erro ao abrir/criar base no firebird

Tags: delphi, firebird

Estou com um problema com o Firebird. Fiz a instalação do Delphi e Firebird, mas quando tento abrir a base ele dá erro. Tentando abrir pelo ibexpert dá o seguinte erro

```
unsuccessful execution caused by an unavailable resource. unavailable database
```

Estou usando a versão 2.5 do Firebird, mas já testei na 1.5 e 3.0. Além disso o serviço do Firebird está em execução no gerenciador de tarefas.

Comment: Essa base está correta? Ela já era usada? Se já era usada, em qual versão do Firebird você usava?

Comment: Está tentando conectar local? Se for isso, no IBExpert coloque Server: Remote / Server Name: 127.0.0.1

Comment: Bom Dia. Você por acaso não tem o Interbase Instalado também?

Comment: Em conformidade com o comentário da @Melissa o link a seguir da uma sugestão que parece solucionar o problema:  
https://rairo.wordpress.com/2011/01/05/firebirdibexpert-ibexpert-unsuccessful-execution-caused-by-an-unavailable-resource/

Answer (score 0):

Para resolver a mensagem *“ibexpert unsuccessful execution caused by an unavailable resource.”* faça assim:

1. Verifique se o servidor do ***firebird*** está ativo.
2. Verifique se a **porta 3050** está liberada no *firewall* do windows ou qualquer bloqueador ou *Firewall* que você tenha.
3. No *ibexpert* na hora de escolher o tipo de Servidor coloque **REMOTE** e Server name coloque o *IP* local da maquina “***127.0.0.1***”
4. Conecte no banco de dados.